# "I was hoping IT WOULD happen" vs "I was hoping IT TO happen"

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct or more common?

> I was hoping **it would happen** and then I was terribly dissapointed.
>
> I was hoping **it to happen** and then I was terribly dissapointed.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. If you use the [edit] to tell us what research you did on your own, it will be easier to answer. Our [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages have good advice on writing a good question. We hope you'll ask more of them!

Comment: The first one is better. The second one is not really wrong but basically is a condensed form of "I was hoping (for) it to happen and then I was terribly *disappointed*."

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I can say that I would probably never say *I was hoping it to happen*.

Answer (score 1):

> I was hoping it to happen and then I was terribly dissapointed.

This sounds like you are using *hope* in the same manner as

> I was finishing the project to completion.

which doesn't make sense really since *hope* is a passive activity.  I can't *hope* a new car into my driveway, but I can *hope* that a new car appears in my driveway somehow.

The speaker/writer may think of *hope* as a non-passive activity (somehow "directing" hope somewhere) but it's not a standard use of *hope*.